# How to connect mongodb in contanier

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I deploy a mongodb in a container. and I also successfully connected to mongodb when my backend runs in the local environment. However, when I tried to move the backend to a container as well, it cannot connect mongodb anymore. The connection string remains the same but it failed.
The error shows that mongodb cannot find the user. However, in my local environment, the same connection string works.

After my googling, most guys said I need to change authSource. I have tried to change authSource to admin, it doesn't work even in my local environment.  And I am sure the user exists in my admin database. not in api_dev_db.  One wired thing is I can connect to mongodb in my local environment but not work in docker.

Could you kindly help me out?

Here I post some pictures.

**These are the env variables I defined in my local environment and they work**

[image: These are the env variables I defined in my local environment and they work]

**This is how I deploy backend service**
[image: This is how I deploy backend service]

**This is my backend dockerfile**
[image: This is my backend dockerfile]

**This is the error when I deploy backend in container**
[image: This is the error when I deploy backend in container]

**This is how I initial mongodb**
[image: This is how I initial mongodb]

Comment: Can you replace the pictures with the actual source code?  It will be much easier to read, potentially run, and search for later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I need to remove '' in env variable, which is MONGO_URL=mongodb://api_user:api1234@mongodb:27017/api_dev_db?authSource=api_dev_db